# Traversing an array of objects from JSON using Boost

Tags: json, boost

I have not been able to solve this problem by my self nor have found some similar question. I have got this JSON:

```
{
"world": {
    "soil": {
        "dimensions": {
            "depth": "200",
            "length": "200",
            "width": "200",
            "cellSize": "1"
        },
        "moisture": {
            "min": "0",
            "max": "100",
            "initialPatches": "30",
            "initialPatchesMaxWidth": "100",
            "initialPatchesSigma": "3",
            "initialPatchesUseRandom": "true"
        },
        "nutrients": {
            "minC": "0",
            "maxC": "23",
            "minN": "0",
            "maxN": "23",
            "minP": "0",
            "maxP": "23"
        },
        "temperature": "25"
    },
    "life": {
        "fungi": [
            {
                "name": "fungus gungus",
                "sporeMass": "0.02"
            },
            {
                "name": "fungus gungusim",
                "sporeMass": "0.04"
            }
        ],
        "fungivores": {
        },
        "predators": {
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I am stalled at trying to recover information for the two different fungi species. I am able to extract simple parameters like depth, initialPatches, etc... But get totally lost on how to traverse all fungi species... Any hints?

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Comment: Are you using Boost to do what you've got working so far?  Which part(s) of Boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google it, you can find several results:

1. [property_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/property_tree.html)
2. [JSON parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html) using above
3. [example](https://gist.github.com/mloskot/1509935) using JSON parser

#### Update

Try this :

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type& child, node.get_child("life.fungi")) {
    std::cout
        << child.second.get<std::string>("sporeMass")
        << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have visited all those three urls before and it is not still clear for me how to access specific values like for example "sporeMass" from them.

Comment: Perfect!!, Thanks a lot. Tried to positively vote yoy but this seems to require at least a 15 reputation... grrrrr. Sorry.